# How to server side include?

Tags: indexing, include

I want to server side include in my webpage, I have `index.html` & `header.html`, how can I make it that the header includes the header file into the `html` file?

The code looks like the one below, but how & where do I need to implement it?

```
<!--#include virtual="presets/header.html" -->
```

to have better information [here is my website](http://sventasticable.nl).

Comment: SSI has to be enabled on the server (perhaps it is only enabled for files with a specific extension, .shtml e.g.). Then just insert the code to your index.(s)html

Comment: By the way: Don't expect someone else to do something *fast*!

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent

Comment: That depends on server software you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have an mac osx server (can't see which version, thus my information might be not exact).

As mentioned in the comments, you must allow the to include things at all. Since you have an apache (default on mac osx) You should follow these informations:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html

On my osx lion server the config file is located here:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

So in gereral:

- stop the apache
- edit the config file
- add the Include code you showed in you question (probably) before (depends on the content of your header.html) the 'body' tag in your index.(s)html file
- restart the apache

If you want to enable SSI in all you files, you could change the suggestion from the ssi howto above into this:

```
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
```

or even

```
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .htm
```